# Solving $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{x}{y}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have solved $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{x}{y}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ using characteristics, to obtain $u(x,y)=C$ (for $y=\pm x$) for $C=0$ and $u(x,y)=f(x^2-y^2)$ for $C$ different than $0$ .

I would now like to use the boundary condition $u(x=y,y)=y$ , but am not quite sure how to go about it. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From the general solution $u(x,y)=f(x^2-y^2)$ ,

Put the boundary condition $u(x=y,y)=y$ :

Then $f(0)=y$ , which is impossible.

$\therefore$ There is no solution.